# Can I use sed to do a variable find and replace depending on what is found?

Tags: linux, text, sed

I am trying to add a line below any instances of lines in a set of file, to check for errno.
The current line format is

`if (ret == <error_val>) return FAIL;`

and I want to add a line below each instance, so that at each location, it will look like this

```
if (ret != <error_val>) return FAIL;
if (errno != <error_val>) return FAIL;
```

But as error_val will differ depending on the scenario (one of EOK|EINVAL|ERANGE) I need to save it from the string found, and use it in the string added.
Is this possible using sed or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Yes, it can be done with sed. Have you tried? We ask that you show your own attempt.

Comment: Hint: `sed -i '/find_regex/s/$/\nnew_text/' file_glob`

Comment: Remembering things in `sed` is slightly pesky; this will probably be significantly easier in Awk.

Comment: @tripleee - with the variable part -- you are right.

Comment: @tripleee: 46 characters in sed (without the filename), not too terrible.